# Can SQLAlchemy be used on its own, independent of framework, and is this recommended?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, node.js, sqlalchemy

I want to use Node.js as my framework, but it doesn't have a good way to manage MySQL Schemas and migrations.

Can I use SQLAlchemy on its own?  Just to sync the tables and create columns, etc....?

And then on my node.js, I would **NOT** use SQLAlchemy for querying or inserting...

Is this recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done.  While I don't have any experience specific to Node.js, I have used SQLAlchemy to:

- set up small databases for non-SQLAlchemy applications.
- query, update, and migrate databases that were not created with SQLAlchemy.
- connect new SQLAlchemy-using applications to existing MySQL databases.

One consideration when using it only to set up the database is that by default, whatever cascades or other referential integrity details you choose define in your model will not be enforced by MySQL itself.  I know it's possible to *let* the back end handle update or delete cascades with the `passive_deletes` and `passive_updates` options, but I don't know if or how you can automatically create these rules on the back end through SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SQLAlchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate) to create/update/downgrade database schemas. It allows you to design the schema as SQLAlchemy model or plain SQL statements (or mixed). You create "versions" of upgrade/downgrade steps for your schema in a local repository, that you then apply to any database SQLAlchemy can talk to.

Answer (score 0):

While using SQLAlchemy's migration tools is a good idea, some of the ORMs for node actually do a reasonable job of taking care of the migration problem. For example, [Persistence JS](http://persistencejs.org/) can sync the database up to the properties declared in your JS file.

Having said this, SQLAlchemy is an excellent choice, I believe - it's flexible enough to handle any database structure you might throw at it (unlike something like Ruby's ActiveRecord, which makes assumptions that may or may not be true in your case).